# Rails update attribute table col1 with col2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mass-assignment

I want to (mass)update a model. Each line of should be updated by replacing the val of attb 1 with the val of attr2

```
users = User.find_all_by_project_id(params[:project_id])
users.each do |d|
  User.update_attribute attribute1 with attribute2
end
```

How is the best way?
Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

That should be done this way:

```
User.where(:project_id => params[:project_id]).update_all('col1 = col2')
```

or

```
User.update_all('col1 = col2', {:project_id => params['project_id'] })
```

Comment: `User.find_all_by_project_id(params[:project_id]).update_all('col1 = col2')` this will probably return an error.

Comment: That's valid, update_all is declared on AR::Relation, calling update_all directly just delegates to Relation and applies the conditions, so they are basically identical calls.

Comment: jvnill is right it fails as dynamic finders work the old-way and return arrays, just tested with 3.2.11

Comment: I did: 
users.each do |d|
User.update_all('col1 = col2', {:id => d.id })
end

Comment: I don't know your app logic but bear in mind that it is not optimal - it produces as many queries as number of users. `User.update_all` with condition should generate only one query which updates all records.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you should do it so everything happens on the sql side.

```
User.update_all("attribute1 = attribute2", { project_id: params[:project_id] })
```